# Can I set a value based on if it's the last record in a group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS 2017, I am comparing the values of a certain column in each group so if the record is more than the previous record in that group, then I want another column to say greater, if it's less then say less, etc.... So the last record in each group shouldn't have anything to compare against and should be the default.

Here is what I have that works except for the last row:

```
=IIF(Fields!margin.Value > Previous(Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem"), "greater than", 
        IIF(Fields!margin.Value < Previous(Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem"), "Less", "Equal"))
```

If I try to use this, I get an error (Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIF' accepts this number of arguments):

```
=IIF((Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem") > Previous(Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem"), "greater than", 
    IIF((Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem") < Previous(Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem"), "Less", "Equal"))
```

I'm really just looking for a way to say If this is the last record in a group then do this. But the last function seems to only find the last value.

Unfortunately I can't do IIF(Fields!margin.Value > Last(Fields!margin.Value, "GroupByItem") because records could easily contain the same values.

Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to output for the last row but you might be able to determine if it's the last row with something like `=IIF( RowNumber("GroupByItem") = MAX(RowNumber("GroupByItem")), "last", "not last")` .

Comment: Good idea but I get the error contains an aggregate function in the argument to another aggregate function or running value.

Comment: Well thankfully my boss decided we didn't need the report this detailed, thanks for your help! It would still be nice to find out how to do this but it's not necessary :)

Comment: Probably not too hard but if you post something like this again. Report design and row/column group layouts make it much easier to understand your scenario.

Comment: Great! I will remember that, thanks!